# How to share a session between Express v4 and Socket.io 1.3.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I've been trying to share an express session to use from socket.io for the past couple of days and I just can't wrap my head around it. I'm using express 4.11.1 with socket.io 1.3.2 (other dependencies are express-session 1.10.1, cookie-parser 1.3.3 and body-parser 1.10.2). I'm basically putting clients data into a session from express and want to use that information in socket.io because sockets loose information on reconnection. What I've done is basically what is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25618636/1069416) but it just doesn't work for me.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    session = require('express-session'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    sessionStore = new session.MemoryStore(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var sessionMiddleware = session({
  name: 'sid',
  store: sessionStore, // MemoryStore
  secret: 's3cr37',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
});

io.use(function(socket, next) {
  sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});

app.use(sessionMiddleware);
app.use(bodyParser.json())

server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res){  
  //just storing the info in session
  req.session.username = req.body.user;
  ...
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  //using socket.request.session.username which doesn't work
  ...
});
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

So, after a lot of messing with this I figured out how to obtain the value from the session in socket. Instead of accessing the value of a session like this:

```
socket.request.session.username
```

I needed to do this:

```
var getUsernameFromSession = function(socket) {
  var sessionId = socket.request.sessionID;
  var cookie = JSON.parse(socket.request.sessionStore.sessions[sessionId]);
  return cookie.username;
};
```

I'm not sure how good this is but this works for me.