# Socket.io middlewhere functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to seperate logic in my socket.io server but i am experiance some issues.

say for instance i have the following:

```
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    var fileModule = require('./costum_modules/FileModule.js')(io);
    app.use(fileModule);

});
```

Now inside the `fileModule` i have the following code:

```
    var fileModule = function (socket) {

    socket.on('userData', function(msg){
        var i = 0;
    });


}

module.exports = new fileModule();
```

Sadly the socket i undefined.

My question is can i do it like this or is it not possible to pass a singleton to another file and make it read from the same object?

Comment: the function `fileModule` take a parameter `socket`. I guess you don't want to do this :`new fileModule()`, but you might want to use the function `fileModule` as parameter of `io.on('connection',fileModule)`

Comment: @Hacketo wouldnt this mean that all the sub files i make has to go into io as a paramater?

Answer (score 0):

You can use other files to break up your logic, but there are a couple issues with your code.

First, I think Hacketo is correct that you don't want to do `new fileModule()`, just:

```
module.exports = fileModule;
```

Second, when call require, you are passing the global socketIO object (`io`).  You should pass it the `socket` you get in the connection handler. E.g.

```
require('./costum_modules/FileModule.js')(socket);
```

I think that will work to move some of your socket.io message handling code into a module.  Now your socket will respond to `userData` messages from a client.  However, unless you have some custom application, I don't think `app.use` is going to do what you expect. You can't hook web socket handlers into an Express/Restify/Connect/Whatever middleware chain.  But you could write a middleware that sends a message to your socket server.

If you are just trying to share the session between your app and socket server, try [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25618636/4686576).