# Passing express session to socket.io

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io

https://github.com/xpepermint/socket.io-express-session
This is one of many ways i tried.
I tried all of these answers as well:
[How to share sessions with Socket.IO 1.x and Express 4.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532692/how-to-share-sessions-with-socket-io-1-x-and-express-4-x)
And some more...It all gives me the exaclty same result:

> throw new TypeError("Parameter 'url' must be a string, not " + typeof
>   url)
>             ^ TypeError: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not undefined

I already tried every solution i found on the internet, basically everything leads me to the same error.
At some point i simply tried copying and pasting examples found and they give me the exactly same results.
I guess something went wrong after one of the middleware updates. How to fix it? Is there another, reliable way to share express session with socket.io?

```
var Session = require('express-session');
var session = Session({ secret: 'pass', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true });
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session); // session support
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  req.session.uid = 1;
  res.send('Hi user #' + req.session.uid);
});


var http = require('http').createServer(app);
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

var ios = require('socket.io-express-session');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.use(ios(session)); // session support
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log(socket.handshake.session);
});
```

Above is an example returning exactly this error.

Answer (score 4):

The error occurs in the stage when you use io.use(...)

The problem is that session middle ware expects to find the session in req.orginalUrl. A socket does not have an orginalUrl. To fix this, simply assign one...

```
io.use(function(socket, next){
  socket.request.originalUrl = socket.request.url;
  session(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});
```

The next problem is going to be that session(...) expects the cookies to be parsed. We can use 'cookie-parser' for this:

```
var cookieParse = cookieParser();
  io.use(function(socket, next){
  cookieParse(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});
```

After that we can simply bridge passport and socket.io:

```
var passInit = passport.initialize();
var passSess = passport.session();
io.use(function(socket, next){
  passInit(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});
io.use(function(socket, next){
  passSess(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});
```

Now in our io.on('connection') we can see socket.request.user

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("socket connection");
  console.log(socket.request.user)
  console.log(socket.request.session.passport.user);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Bradley Lederholz's answer, this is how I made it work for myself. Please refer to Bradley Lederholz's answer, for more explanation.

```
var app = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io');
var cookieParse = require('cookie-parser')();
var passport = require('passport');
var passportInit = passport.initialize();
var passportSession = passport.session();
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var sessionMiddleware = session({
  secret: 'some secret',
  key: 'express.sid',
  resave: true,
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  ephemeral: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {},
  store:new mongoStore({
  mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
  db: 'mydb'
  });
});

app.use(sessionMiddleware);
io = io(server);
io.use(function(socket, next){
  socket.client.request.originalUrl = socket.client.request.url;
  cookieParse(socket.client.request, socket.client.request.res, next);
});

io.use(function(socket, next){
  socket.client.request.originalUrl = socket.client.request.url;
  sessionMiddleware(socket.client.request,   socket.client.request.res, next);
});

io.use(function(socket, next){
  passportInit(socket.client.request, socket.client.request.res, next);
});

io.use(function(socket, next){
  passportSession(socket.client.request, socket.client.request.res, next);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  ...
});

... 
server.listen(8000);
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I still cannot access passport