# Socket.io can't access same session as Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, socket.io

I'm trying to use express and socket.io with shared sessions, I got it already once working, but somehow it won't work anymore.

I followed this link [How to share sessions with Socket.IO 1.x and Express 4.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532692/how-to-share-sessions-with-socket-io-1-x-and-express-4-x) and got access to session on socket.io, but it's not somehow same session. It seems that every socket.io connection it generates new session.

**Express**

req.session.test == 'Some value'

**Socket.io**

socket.request.session.test == undefined

Am I missing something, or is it a bug with some of those modules?

**-- Edit -- Edit -- Edit --**

Found what causes the problem is that i when I set cookie with following

```
cookie: {
    domain: '.local.fi' 
}
```

I need to have same session across subdomains, how can I do it if not this way as many pages succested?

**-- Edit -- Edit -- Edit --**

**package.json**

```
{
   "dependencies": {
      "express": "^4.13.4",
      "express-session": "^1.13.0",
      "socket.io-session": "^0.0.5",
      "express-socket.io-session": "^1.3.1",    
       "socket.io": "^1.4.5"
   }
}
```

**Start of my index.js**

```
'use strict'
var express = require('express'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server)
```

I create sessionMiddleware like this

```
let connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/sessions')
var sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: 'session-secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    name: 'sess.sid',
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: connection,
        ttl: 60 * 60 * 172800
    }),
    cookie: {
        domain: '.local.fi',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 172800
    }
})
```

And attach it like this

```
app.use(sessionMiddleware)
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next)    
})
```

Express routes

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if(!req.session.test)
        req.session.test = 'Some value'
    res.send(`
        <html>
            <head>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type='text/javascript' src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var sio = io.connect('localhost')
                        sio.on('connected', function(data) {
                            $('#list').empty()
                            console.log(data)
                        })
                        sio.on('broadcast', function(data) {
                            $('#list').append($(data))
                        })
                    })
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h5> Session result => ${req.session.test} </h5>
                <div>
                    <ul id='list'></ul>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>

    `)
})
```

Socket.io routes

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('Client connected')
    socket.emit('connected', { response: 'connection', session: socket.request.session})
    var tick = 0
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        tick++
        socket.emit('broadcast', `<li>Tick ${socket.request.session.test}</li>`)
        if(tick>100)
            clearInterval(interval)
    }, 1000)
})
```

**And end of index.js**

```
server.listen(80)
console.log('Test listening port 80')
```

I tried also with these but without any help

**socket.io-session** https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-session

**express-socket.io-session** https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session

Comment: how are you verifying your changes? Have you removed all session storage/cookies after making changes?

Comment: Yes I cleared all cookies from browser and cleared all session data from mongodb. I found resolution for my issue and will answer for my own question for futher readers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**✓ Found resolution for this issue.**

Problem was when I connect socket.io on client side.

I set cookie domain as .local.fi and connected to localhost

On declaration

```
cookie: {
    domain: '.local.fi'
}
```

Clientside

**From**

```
var socket = io.connect('localhost')
```

**To**

```
var socket = io.connect('local.fi')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change

```
session = session({...
```

to

```
sessionMiddleware = session({...
```

You are overwriting the session variable that you declare earlier in

```
session = require('express-session')
```

so you are most likely running into conflicts by doing that. So you would have

```
var sessionMiddleware = session({
  secret: 'session-secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  name: 'sess.sid',
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: connection,
    ttl: 60 * 60 * 172800
  }),
  cookie: {
    domain: '.local.fi',
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 172800/*,
    expires: moment().add(7, 'days')*/
  }
})
app.use(sessionMiddleware)
io.use(function(socket, next) {
  sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next)    
})
```

Comment: I'm actually using variable sessionMiddleware, but it doesn't help or make any changes, fixed this part into my question.