# Socket.io trigger from server

Tags: node.js, triggers, server, socket.io, notifications

I'm asking myself : "How could I trigger an IO event to a specific user (like notification when sucess on something)". But on a post request for example I don't have any socket objet.

I want to be able to do this: (should I store the socket object in a cookie? Or there are other possibilities availible?)

```js
app.post('/askChangeUserPass', ChangePassIfCorrect , function (req, res){
    if (req.session) {

        if ( req.data == 1 ){
            return res.send("1") // socket.emit("notification", {})
        } else {
            return res.send("req.data") // socket.emit("notification", {})
        }

    } else {
        return res.render("404")
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears you already have a session for each user, then the usual way to do this is to store the `socket.id` in the session when the user connects with socket.io.  Then, from any http request, you can get the `socket.id` from the session and use:

```
// get socketid from session
io.to(socketid).emit(...)
```

For sharing a session between socket.io and express, see:

[How to share sessions with Socket.IO 1.x and Express 4.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532692/how-to-share-sessions-with-socket-io-1-x-and-express-4-x)

And, when the socket.io connection is created in the `connect` event, you can set the socket.id into the session.

Comment: I see, but how to store the socket.id in my session, I'm using express-session, and I have it on every request (request.session) but I can't imagine how to link the socket.id obtained in the io.on("connection", function(socket) ) to my session.socketId

Comment: @Izio - In the link to the share sessions post in my answer, it shows you how to get access to the session from any `socket`.  So, in the `connect` event, you can do `socket.request.session.socketid = socket.id;` (and then perhaps save your session data if your session store needs an explicit save).  Then, in any of your other request handlers, you can access `req.session.socketid`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to have each client join a user-specific channel when they first connect/login, and then at any time later you can emit to that channel to communicate with all of those instances.

Instance joins the user-specific channel (on connect or login, etc):

```
socket.join(user.id)
```

Server emits a message to each instance (in your POST request, etc):

```
socket.server.to(user.id).emit(...)
```