# routing in express with socket.io data

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to access data of socket.id outside of `io.on()` function...
with `io.on('connection')` I counted every each user logged in my app and put in an array, but I want to send different pages according to the socket.id that each user have.

How can I achieve this?

```
[...]
var row_of_users = [];//my array of users.
var visits = 0;//just a count of users logged in.

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    var user = socket.id;
    visits++;
    row_of_users.push(user);
    console.log(row_of_users);
[...]
```

Outside of the function I have my express function:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if(row_of_users == 0) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
    } else if (row_of_users < 0) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname+'/wait-your-time.html');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the socket io information with express middleware. See this answer: [How to share sessions with Socket.IO 1.x and Express 4.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532692/how-to-share-sessions-with-socket-io-1-x-and-express-4-x)