# Cannot read property 'session' of undefined node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I am trying to use `express-session` for session management. It works okay inside functions I create, but inside `socket.io` it doesn't work at all.

Here's what I have:

```
   socket.on('chat_message', function(message, req) {


    if (req.session.lang) {
        translate(message, null, req.session.lang, true).then(res => {
            console.log(res.translation);
    
            io.to(socket.id).emit('chat_message', '<strong>p' + socket.username + '</strong>: ' + res.translation);
    
            }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            });
     }
    });
})
```

it is giving me the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined
```

on the if statement line: `if (req.session.lang) {`

why isn't this working? I have express-session defined as well.

Comment: `socket.on` gets an event and a callback. the callback arguments are which you pass in the `socket.emit` function. This is not an express route callback!

Comment: @Gianluca this link may help you to access session in socket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532692/how-to-share-sessions-with-socket-io-1-x-and-express-4-x