# Why won't socket.io and express-session use next function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io, express-session

I'm trying to use the express-session library in my MERN stack app along with socket.io for the real time messaging part of the app.

For authentication I am using express-session and would like to use that same middleware for socket connections, however when I followed the answer for the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532692/how-to-share-sessions-with-socket-io-1-x-and-express-4-x), the middlware just simply didn't proceed to the next function and so when trying to connect, the middlware never went to the onConnect handler and the handshake never completed.

```
const day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // ms

const sessionStore = MongoStore.create({
    mongoUrl: "mongodb://localhost:27017/zooit",
    collection: "sessions"
});

// defining the session middlware from express-session
const session = () => expressSession({
    secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: day * 30
    }
});

// session middlware fine with express
app.use(session());

io.use((socket, next) => {
    // won't use next function
    session(socket.request, {}, next);

    // tried doing this but then in the handler session.request.session was undefined
    // next();
});

io.on("connection", require("./socket-controllers/onConnect"));
io.on("disconnect", require("./socket-controllers/onDisconnect"));
```

```
// onConnect.js
function onConnect(socket) {
    // this function isn't reached when not calling next but when explicitly calling next() socket.request.session is undefined
    console.log(`User connected: ${socket.request.session}`);
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how I should proceed that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update, I found the answer.

In the socket.io documentation it goes over how you are able to use middleware and express-session.

Crucially it gives a wrapper function which seems to sort things:

```
const wrap = middleware => (socket, next) => middleware(socket.request, {}, next);
```

From here you wrap the express-session middleware already defined in an io.use:

```
io.use(wrap(session()));
```

Now I can access the session like so:

```
socket.request.session
```

Hope this helps anyone struggling with the same issue.